# Is there a way to join two lists with the corresponding information from an xarray data variable?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have two lists, list1 and list2.

```
list1 = [wind_speed_0, wind_speed_1, wind_direction_0, 
         wind_direction_1]

list2 = [serial_num_0, serial_num_1]
```

The items in these lists are actually the names of data variables that belong to an xarray dataset.

Essentially, if the last characters in list2 match the last characters in list1, then I want to take the corresponding serial number for each item in list2 and append it on to the items in list1.

For example: "abc123" is the serial number assigned to serial_num_0, and "abc456" is the serial number assigned to serial_num_1. So, I would want to end up with a list3 that would look like this:

```
list3 = [wind_speed_abc123, wind_speed_abc456, 
        wind_direction_abc123,wind_direction_abc456]
```

Is there an easy way to do this that's slipping my mind?

This is what I have so far:

```
# Collect all possible items for lists from xarray dataset object

want_variables = ['wind_speed_.*','wind_direction_.*']
serial_nums = ['serial_num_.*']

# Give me all of the data variables found in my xarray dataset

obj_variables = list(ds.data_vars) 

# Use for loops to create list1 and list2

for var in want_variables:
    r = re.compile(var)
    list1 = list(filter(r.match, obj_variables))

    for ii in serial_nums:
        rr = re.compile(ii)
        list2 = list(filter(rr.match, obj_variables))
```

This gets me list1 and list2, but I am unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: Does my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the matching sequence as an index for a reference dictionary which stores each value under a key (column):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# build the regular expression
pattern = re.compile('_([0-9]+)')

# build a lambda to use in for loop
f = lambda x: int(pattern.findall(x)[0])


ref_dict = {}

# assign all data to idx & cols:
for x in list1 + list2:
  idx = f(x)
  col = x.split('_'+str(idx))[0]
  if idx not in ref_dict.keys():
    ref_dict[idx] = {col:x}
  else:
    ref_dict[idx][col] = x

df = pd.DataFrame(ref_dict).T 

print(df)
#      serial_num    wind_direction    wind_speed
# 0  serial_num_0  wind_direction_0  wind_speed_0
# 1  serial_num_1  wind_direction_1  wind_speed_1
```